# How to enable GTK theming (wine-staging) in Playonlinux?

Tags: wine, gtk, playonlinux

As indicated in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/756781/47206), Wine-staging now has an option for GTK theming, and it works as indicated there.

Adding a Wine-staging version to a virtual drive in Playonlinux , the "Staging" tab appears in Wine configuration for that drive, but "Enable GTK Theming" is grayed-out.

[image]

[image]

How could I get the GTK theming to work in Playonlinux?

---

Following the linked solution, both `wine-staging` and `winehq-staging` are installed. I think `wine-staging` is [a development branch of Wine](https://www.wine-staging.com/) but I don't know about `winehq-staging`.

`winehq-staging` needs and installs `wine-staging` in order to work, but I don't think Playonlinux installs `winehq-staging` and **that** may be the problem.

---

Having that in Playonlinux would be an advantage because of the easier of using different Wine versions for different programs, as gtk theming may not really represent a progress for all windows programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We (PlayOnLinux team) are currently creating a new wine build system. We plan to add GTK support soon.

The current wine builds (build with the legacy system) do not support GTK+ because wine staging is not compiled with libgtk-dev at that time.

---

UPDATES:

- POL 4 has been updated on October 18, 2018 to support this new wine
  build system. We will write a news on the website, probably this
  week. See also [Add support for Wine
  staging](https://github.com/PhoenicisOrg/phoenicis-winebuild/issues/8).
- 24/11/2018: Last wine staging builds now support GTK 3.

Comment: POL 4 has been updated yesterday o support this new wine build system. We will write a news on the website, probably this week

Comment: (See https://github.com/PhoenicisOrg/phoenicis-winebuild/issues/8)

Comment: For the moment I see no details on that, the link you posted shows a comment that sends back here. Would the gtk support come through adding `winehq-staging` or simply through a certain new wine version?

Comment: GTK+ comes with wine-staging. However, wine needs to be compiled with libgtk devel installed on the build system (which is not the case currently). This is probably why the box is disabled on your screenshot.

Comment: If you want to try manually, you can build fairly easily your custom winebuild with gtk3 support: 
- Clone this repository: github.com/PhoenicisOrg/phoenicis-winebuild
- Install docker
- Install py docker : pip install docker
- Run PYTHONPATH="$PWD" python examples/wine_staging_builder.py

It should generate a wine-staging.tar.gz file, that you can install into ~/.PlayOnLinux/wine/linux-x86

Answer (score 2):

You can do the following:

-[Install wine-staging](https://wine-staging.com/installation.html) (`winehq-staging`) in your system (not from POL). It must replace `wine`.

-Go to POL and in "Wine version" select "System".

Now you can check "enable GTK3 theming".

Comment: In fact it's `winehq-staging`: https://wine-staging.com/installation.html

Comment: I now want a more specific answer, relating to how to do the same in Playonlinux. There may be cases were I do not want to install another version of wine at system level.